# I have questions on problems on the textbook/ from the textbook?

Tags: grammar

When you want to email your teacher to ask questions on problems on a textbook, which one should I use?

I have some questions on problems on the textbook

I have some questions on problems from the textbook

Or is there any other way of saying this?

Comment: I have questions on the textbook problems.

Answer (score 1):

They mean different things. You will need to decide which matches your situation.

> I have some questions on problems **on** the textbook.

This means regarding the textbook itself. A better way to say this might be:

> I have some questions on problems **regarding** the textbook. I think it is too old and does not address current affairs.

As for:

> I have some questions on problems **from** the textbook.

This refers to problems taken *from* the pages the textbook. Of course they are written on the pages in this example.

Finally you could also write:

> I have some questions on problems **in** the textbook.

meaning problems written *inside* (on the pages of) the textbook. I think this would be the best option if you are referring to problems written in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is preferable. To modify that a little bit, I would say

> I have questions on some (of the) problems from the textbook.

or

> I have questions on some textbook problems.